# python regular expression search not finding underscore in path

Tags: python, regex

I have a long file which follows some structure and I want to parse this file to extract an object called `sample`:

The file named `paths_text.txt` is like that:

```
/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001G_1_Clean.fastq.gz
/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001G_2_Clean.fastq.gz
/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001T_1_Clean.fastq.gz
/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001T_2_Clean.fastq.gz
```

My code runs fine like this:

```
import os
os.chdir('/groups/cgsd/alexandre/python_code')
import re


with open('./src/paths_text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        sample = re.search(r'pfg\d+',line)
        print(sample)
```

But when I search for underscore I get `None` as a result of my match, why?

```
import os
os.chdir('/groups/cgsd/alexandre/python_code')
import re


with open('./src/paths_text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        sample = re.search(r'pfg\d+_',line)
        print(sample)
```

Comment: what pattern do u want to extract?

Comment: first sample is pfg001G_1. I want to extract `r('pfg\d+{G or T}_{1or2})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Becuase there's `G` and `T` between `pfg001` and `_`. `\d+` only counts numbers.

Comment: @alex There can be many ways to solve depending on file name format. You can try ```pfg.+_``` or ```pfg[\dGT]+_```, ```pfg\d+[A-Z]_```.

Comment: @alex If you want to do ```r('pfg\d+{G or T}_{1or2})```, you can use ```pfg\d+[GT]_[12]```